# How does a Bellman-Ford with FIFO Queue speed up its iteration?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, bellman-ford

My lecturer mentions this:

• Try to decrease the running time of one iteration of loop 1: consider only edges which may give effective relax operations.

• A vertex v is active, if the edges outgoing from v have not been relaxed
since the last time d[v] has been decreased.

• Perform RELAX only on edges outgoing from active vertices.

• Store active vertices in the Queue data structure.

My question is, how does a FIFO Queue speed up Bellman-Ford's iterations? In what circumstances do you 'enqueue'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue is there only because it is a convenient data-structure to keep track of the active nodes.

You enqueue a node when you first try to relax an edge connected to that node. By the time you reach the node, you will have relaxed all edges from active neighbors onto that node.

Doing those steps transforms the Bellman-Ford algorithm into something closer to [Dijksta's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).

---

If node is *active*, it is next up for consideration. You also have *visited* nodes, which you already have determined everything you need to know about. And nodes that has not yet been reached is *unvisited*.

You can think of the three statuses as colors. You start off with just the initial node being colored *active*, and everything else being *unvisited*. As you move along, the *active* color will move outwards forming a border surrounding the *visited* nodes. You are done when you have no more *active* nodes, and everything is colored *visited*.

---

As an alternative to the queue, you could use two lists. The first one contains the *active* nodes you are currently considering, and any new *active* nodes you put into the second list. After the first list is exhausted, you empty it, and swap the two lists. Using a single queue instead, you blend the iterations together, by not having a distinct border between the current iteration, and the next.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm still not clear on how exactly a FIFO Queue would reduce the number of iterations for Bellman-Ford...for starters, what is an 'active' node?

Comment: I just realized that you may have been describing the wrong algorithm...Bellman-Ford relaxes the table via inputted edges ran over n times, not visiting nodes...

Comment: With the introduction of active vertices, it becomes very different from the original. Here is my interpretation of it: http://ideone.com/qwp2zP (C#)

Comment: I think what my lecturer meant was, if the shortest path distance to node x has decreased, enqueue it to the active nodes. Dequeue nodes when you have considered all its edges. But thanks anyway :)